# empty lines are missing in webview

Tags: android, html, webview

> Suppose `Html` body is having below content

```
qwweeerrt

asssdfghjjkl

zxxcvbnmm
```

> It is shown like below :

`qwweeerrtasssdfghjjklzxxcvbnmm`

> when I used

```
webView.loadData()
```

and 
qwweeerrt asssdfghjjkl zxxcvbnmm when I used

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL()
```

So empty lines between qwweeerrt , asssdfghjjkl and zxxcvbnmm are missing in webview.

Please suggest me how to show the content as it is.

Comment: Well, the WebView is desigend to show HTML content. So your best bet is to formulate what you want to have as an HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'content' has to be more formatted. Proper way to show it would be like.

```
<p>qwweeerrt</p>
<p>asssdfghjjkl</p>
<p>zxxcvbnmm</p>
```

See what the `webView.loadData()` shows now.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I had to replace \r\n\r\n with </p><p> now it will become like <p>qwweeerrt</p>
<p>asssdfghjjkl</p>
<p>zxxcvbnmm</p> so content will be shown in next line.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML** (not the WebView itself) hates blanks.
Please use the `<br/>` tag to add a carriage return.
Double it, for an empty line.

If you want to add some blank spaces, use `&nbsp;` for each space you want.

Or, as an alternative, include your text in a

```
<pre>
    Your multiline text here
    Second line
    Third line
</pre>
```

structure.

The WebView only renders the HTML (but also CSS and JavaScript).
And it does a great job.

I recommend you to study some HTML, if you plan to use a WebView in your app.
A great (and historically proven to be accurate) learning source is found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thank you, dear!